# Action of  Co-quasi-triangular Universal r-form on $a \otimes 1$

Tags: hopf-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

A very easy question I can't seem to answer: For a universal r-form on a co-quasi-triangular Hopf algebra why is $r(a \otimes 1) = r(1 \otimes a) = \epsilon(a)$?

Comment: John,

To my mind, co-quasitriangular Hopf algebras and quasitriangular Hopf algebras are essentially equivalent notions (the only real difference is that co-modules are automatically locally finite, whereas modules need to be explicitly declared as such for $R$-matrix to converge in many common examples).  In particular, any statement about the former is just the adjoint of the latter.  So looking at Proposition 2 in Chapter 8, where the analogous statement is proven for $R$-matrices, will show you the proof for $r$-forms.  It looks like you will do some trick with writing $r=r\cdot 1$.

Comment: I'll check back in a day or so and see if you want more details.

Comment: Sorry Proposition 2, Chapter eight, in Klymik and Schmudgen's text.  I seem to have gone from your previous thread to this one, and carried the same standing references =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like David said, the proof is almost identical to the earlier one for $R$-matrices:

$r(x\otimes 1) = r\circ (id\otimes\mu)(x\otimes 1\otimes 1) = (r_{13}\ast r_{12})(x\otimes 1\otimes1)= \sum r(x'\otimes 1)r(x''\otimes 1) = (r \ast r)(x\otimes 1).$

Since $r$ is invertible, $r(x\otimes 1)=\epsilon(x)$.